# Java, modify a file excel

Tags: java, excel

I would like to know if there is a way in java to edit an excel file.
For example: if I have an excel sheet populated, I can change the value of certain cells while leaving the value of others?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please remove the itext tag from this question. iText doesn't have any XLS functionality.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you using a library? Which one? Post some code snippets, show you have done some research on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it nicely using Andy Khan's [JExcel](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) library.

Comment: Can you make me a simple example? please :)

Comment: C'mon, man.  At least look at the docs and try the stuff that Andy gives you.  Some effort on your part beyond whining.

Comment: @duffymo isn't that API obsolete ? Do you know it works also on products released after 2003 year ?

Answer (score 5):

`JXL` is designed for increased read efficiency (since this is the primary use of the API). In order to improve performance, data which relates to output information (eg. all the formatting information such as fonts) is not interpreted when the spreadsheet is read, since this is superfluous when interrogating the raw data values.

However, if we need to modify this spreadsheet a handle to the various write interfaces is needed, which can be obtained using the copy method.

```
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("myfile.xls"));
WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("temp.xls"), workbook);
```

This copies the information that has already been read in as well as performing the additional processing to interpret the fields that are necessary to for writing spreadsheets. The disadvantage of this read-optimized strategy is that we have two spreadsheets held in memory rather than just one, thus doubling the memory requirements.

**But after this, you can do whatever you want. Like:**

```
WritableSheet sheet2 = copy.getSheet(1); 
WritableCell cell = sheet2.getWritableCell(1, 2); 

if (cell.getType() == CellType.LABEL) 
{ 
  Label l = (Label) cell; 
  l.setString("modified cell"); 
}
copy.write(); 
copy.close();
workbook.close();
```

Comment: In itext, can i do this?

Comment: Frankly speaking i have used itext for pdf, but i have done this flawlessly with JXL

Answer (score 4):

I have some decent results with the Apache POI library: http://poi.apache.org/

It even works on Android.

Comment: Apache POI is indeed convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) API to edit an excel sheet

Answer (score 1):

use can use JXL to do this

the JXL doesnt provide a direct way of reading and writing to the same file (might seem inconvenient to you but the JXL says this is because reading is main function(mostly used) and this improves performance , I though would have preferred a readwrite streat on a workbook myself)

example

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.util.Date; 
import jxl.*; 
import jxl.write.*; 

//open read to your workbook (readonly)
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("myfile.xls"));

//create a copy workbook on which you will write
WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("output.xls"), workbook);

//modify existing cell 
WritableSheet sheet2 = copy.getSheet(1); 
WritableCell cell = sheet2.getWritableCell(2, 4); 

NumberFormat fivedps = new NumberFormat("#.#####"); 
WritableCellFormat cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat(fivedps); 
cell.setFormat(cellFormat);

//add cells 
Label label = new Label(0, 2, "New label record"); 
sheet2.addCell(label); 

Number number = new Number(3, 4, 3.1459); 
sheet2.addCell(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write some utility to do this, however it is possible to do in JXL.

Please note there is a bug in SheetCopier.java, L996+997:
wrong:

```
    if (c.getCellFeatures() != null &
        c.getCellFeatures().hasDataValidation())
```

should be:

```
    if (c.getCellFeatures() != null &&
        c.getCellFeatures().hasDataValidation())
```

Since i dont have Andy Khans email I cannot contact him, so rebuild the sources too.

As a side note, Apache poi is far too complicated for mortals, and the class names are ridiculous, and in my experience apache code is unfriendly, unhelpful, and not robust. So I avoid apache when possible.

Comment: I know this has been half a year, but inspired by your post on the front page asking about your account getting locked out, I needed to let you know that this code will work just fine as written.

According to the language spec, [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2), if the inputs of the bitwise operator are boolean, the result is a boolean operation. This should work just fine.

Comment: @John, to state the obvious, "&" computes both parts, where "&&" uses lazy evaluation. The expression with & breaks if c.getCellFeatures()==null, because "c.getCellFeatures().hasDataValidation()" will be computed nevertheless too, resulting in a NPE which is not what was intended, or else the code part "c.getCellFeatures() != null" would be unneeded.

Comment: I just wanted to say that jxl is a great and easy to work with library, easier than apache poi, so to get a program quickly up and running you should use jxl. Apache poi supports the newer excel, however, but in prototype phase you will get bogged down by its complexity.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Thanks for the explanation!